# How to delete evaluated function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, memory, memory-management, memory-leaks

I have a script that looks like this:

```
arr.map(v => {
  v[0] = new Function(`
    try {
      if (${v[1]?.before}) {
        let func = ${v[0]};
        const rtn = func.call(this, this); // call function passed before deconstruction of tooltip
        func = undefined;
        
        this?.tooltip?.deconstruct(${misc?.fadeOut}); // deconstruction of tooltip
        return rtn;
      } else {
        this?.tooltip?.deconstruct(${misc?.fadeOut}); // deconstruction of tooltip

        let func = ${v[0]};
        const rtn = func.call(this, this); // call function passed after deconstruction of tooltip
        func = undefined;

        return rtn;
      }
    } catch(err) {
      return console.error(err); // TODO: remove in production
    }
  `);

  const bounded = v[0].bind(this); // bind tooltip to function so this.tooltip.deconstruction can be called
  v[0] = undefined;

  return [ bounded, v[1], v[2] ];
});
```

In the script, `v[0]` is always a function, `v[1]` gives information on what to do with the function, and variables `v[2]` and `misc` can be ignored for this question. This code is suppose to create a function for an eventListener, that when called, will destroy the tooltip that the function is connected to. However, every time this code executes, I get a new function that shows up in my loaded scripts in vscode, and I'm worried this may create a memory leak. Is there a way to delete these functions? Or should I writ the code differently?

Here is what my vscode debug looks like (this is from the live preview extension)

[image: Image of all the eval functions after just a bit of running]

If you need more information, I will send you it.

I've tried deleting the function using argument.callee, and tried deleting it when the event listener is removed, however they were all local scope. I'm expecting for the function to be removed from the loaded scripts.

Comment: You can't delete objects from memory in JS. Rather design your code so, that it can utilize automatic garbage collection. In your case, don't create a function using `new` operator, use a suitable parametrized function expression instead, which is carbage collected after use.

Comment: There are very very few reasons to construct functions from string bodies in JavaScript. It's slow and messy. I've seen over the past 20 years maybe two cases where it seemed like an OK (not necessarily great, but OK) idea, but those involved some performance considerations that definitely don't apply with modern JavaScript.

Comment: @Teemu thank you, I will try this once I have a chance to.

Comment: @Pointy Good to know. I use `new Function()` a lot and should have known better not to as it is really messy and I already know not to use `eval()`... don't know what I was thinking.

Comment: If your object no longer has any reference anywhere in your code AND in the DOM, then both the object and any listeners attached to it will get removed from memory by garbage collection. But if you are programming a tooltip, a much better way to do it is just creating one single tooltip that either shows up or is hidden. No need to create functions dynamically!

Comment: @Kokodoko This is what I was assuming the problem was since I have other dynamic functions that don’t have the same problem. But I can’t find anywhere that references the function, probably just need to spend some time actually debugging…

Comment: Don't forget that creating and destroying items is always more "expensive" than keeping a single tooltip hidden in the DOM. The mouseover listener can move the tooltip to the mouse and make it visible. The mouseout listener just makes it invisible. That will save you a lot of "creation / destruction" code.

Comment: @Kokodoko Thank you for the help! I'll play around with it for a bit!